# Cómo logro que un blob type se transforme en imagen o canvas con Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, img, blob

Necesito obtener la imagen partiendo de la urlBlob, ya sea en canvas ó en img.-
Vengo lidiando un rato largo y no emboco una solución. Agradeceré la ayuda.-

```
function miImagen(resultado){
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(resultado);
urlBlob= image.src;
console.log(urlBlob);
}
```

Lo que obtengo en la consola: `blob:http://localhost:63342/6a1963a7-d3c2-443f-8b37-e7d92460f107` y lo quiero tener canvas o en img.-

Comment: esa ruta, el content type lo tienes como imagen?

Comment: Esto `urlBlob= image.src;`  parece sobrar, pero el resto del código debería funcionar. Cual es el problema?

Comment: Hello Jack. Yes, image/jepg

Comment: Hola Yussef.  sí, urlBlob= image.src es redundante. El problema es cómo logro que Blob: http://localhost:63342/6a1963a7-d3c2-443f-8b37-e7d92460f107 llevarlo a la página como imagen o canvas